# Add another button to navigation bar

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I'm modifying an app and this app has some buttons in its navigation bar, I wanted to add another button or Bar Button item by dragging it to the hierarchy but it seems I can't add it as a child to navigation bar, I wanted to ask if you have any solutions to this, here's a snapshot of the hierarchy of the storyboard, I want to add another Bar Button Item or another Button to the Navigation item.
Thanks
[image]

Comment: There is no picture, please upload a picture.

Comment: Thanks very much I attached it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems you can only have 3 elements on navigation bar with Interface Builder and you have to add more buttons via code. This link worked for me :
http://mandarapte.com/apple/add-navigation-bar-buttons-ios-app-xcode-project/

Answer (score 21):

So I've just created a blank project and I can do this:

[image]

I've also done stuff like this before where I actually use a UIButton rather than a bar button item gaining some extra customisability. Just make sure that you set an outlet to the button and in the view controller call `self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:self.customButton];`:

[image]

You can have multiple right bar button items and if they overlap the title (if you have one) then they are essentially clipped. From my understanding, you can have as many buttons as you like until the space is gone (which can vary depending on the device, obviously). Relevant docs:

> This array can contain 0 or more bar button items to display on the right side of the
>   navigation bar. Items are displayed right-to-left in the same order as they appear in the array. Thus, the first item in the array is the rightmost item and other items are added to the left of the previous item.
>
> If there is not enough room to display all of the items in the array, those that would overlap the title view (if present) or the buttons on the left side of the bar are not
>   displayed.

An example with lots of buttons:

[image]

Programatically you can add buttons using:

`navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = [aButton, anotherButton, awesomeButton]`

Just make sure you test that the smallest device you target will still provide a good UX for the user if you add lots of buttons.

Comment: Wow , thanks man the gifs were amazing. can there be more than 3 items ? because the project I'm working on has already 2 buttons and one image , and what I'm trying to do is to add a third button. Thanks agin

Comment: @m0j1 You certainly can have a third right button item. I've updated my answer with more details.

Answer (score 8):

here is the correct answer for swift :

```
let barButton_array: [UIBarButtonItem] = [Button1, Button2]
navigationItem.setRightBarButtonItems(barButton_array, animated: false)
```